Add a time range to a virtual dataset on superset with JINJA
I can use the following query with JINJA in Superset's SQL Lab:
SELECT {{ current_username() }}

and it returns the user name. But when I use the following query:
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE dttm_col > '{{ from_dttm }}' and dttm_col < '{{ to_dttm }}'

it returns this error:

Failed to execute query '128'. The following parameters in your query are undefined: 'from_dttm", "to_dttm". Please check your templates parameters for syntax errors and make sure they match across your SQL query and et Parameters.

